# Bash script to continuously execute binary even the binary crashes

Tags: linux, bash

I have two binary files that I need to run (e.g., *hello1* and *hello2* and the order has to be *hello1* followed by *hello2*), but from time to time *hello2* crashes and when it crashes I need to manually restart *hello2*. I want a Bash script to keep checking the status of *hello1* and *hello2* and if either of them crashes then I want to start *hello1* and *hello2*.

On Linux is checking the PIDs of *hello1* and *hello2* the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Run the commands directly as the condition of an `until` loop.

```
while :; do
   until hello1; do :; done
   until hello2; do :; done
done
```

If you only need to run each command once, you can omit the enclosing `while` loop.

The `:` is a do-nothing command required by the syntax of the loop. All you really want is for the loop to exit once the command has a succesful exit status.